# (Swift 3) Trying to sort an array of class objects by Date in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have an array of objects that has a member that is type `Date`, and I'm trying to sort the whole array by `Date`, and it's not sorting correctly.
This is the code I'm using, the name of the array is `alarms` and the name of the member type `Date` is `time`.

```
alarms.sort(by: { $0.time.compare($1.time) == .orderedAscending })
```

and whenever I sort it it just doesn't work correctly, and I'm testing it by printing all the values in a `for` loop.

Can someone help me with the syntax for this?

Comment: `Date` doesn't have a `time` property. Where does this come from?

Comment: @TomHarrington - I think `time` is the name of a `Date` property of his alarm type.

Comment: self.messages.sort(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending })
Works for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `compare` is a `NSDate` function. With `Date` you can just use `<` operator. For example:

```
alarms.sort { $0.time < $1.time }
```

---

Having said that, `compare` should work, too, though. I suspect there's some deeper issue here, that perhaps your `time` values have different dates. You might only be looking at the time portion, but when comparing `Date` objects, it considers both the date and time. If you only want to look at the time portion, there are several ways of doing that, for example, look at the time interval between `time` and the start of the day:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

alarms.sort {
    let elapsed0 = $0.time.timeIntervalSince(calendar.startOfDay(for: $0.time))
    let elapsed1 = $1.time.timeIntervalSince(calendar.startOfDay(for: $1.time))
    return elapsed0 < elapsed1
}
```

There are lots of ways to do this, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: I think they do have different dates! And thanks for that rob, I'll try that and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I'm getting errors with the Calendar.startOfDay part, this is the error that I'm getting

     Use of instance member 'startOfDay' on type 'Calendar'; did you mean to use a value of type 'Calendar' instead?

Comment: thanks worked perfect                     sameTitleArr.sort { $0.startDate > $1.startDate }
for descending