# Sorting a tuple array of Strings that contains a date in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I currently have a tuple array whose's first value is of type `String` and second value of type `Double`. The first value contains a date, and is in the format `"MM/dd/yy"`.

I'm not using `Date` objects due to confliction in my code.

I'm having trouble sorting this array by String in descending order (recent to oldest) because of the `MM`.

For example, my array contains the following:

```
[("07/30/17", 5.0), ("08/30/17", 9.0), ("05/30/17", 5.0), ("05/28/17", 6.0)]
```

Calling `tupleArray = tupleArray.sort( {$0.0 > $1.0} )` would produce the following:

```
[("08/30/17", 9.0), ("07/30/17", 5.0), ("05/30/17", 5.0), ("05/28/17", 6.0)]
```

That works as expected.

However, if I add a `String` entry `"08/30/16"`, calling the same sort function produces the following:

```
[("08/30/17", 9.0), ("08/30/16", 30.0), ("07/30/17", 5.0), ("05/30/17", 5.0), ("05/28/17", 6.0)]
```

`"08/30/16"` is in the 2nd index when it should be the last index, because the year `16` is older then `17`.

I've looked at:

1. [(Swift 3) Trying to sort an array of class objects by Date in swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39605477/2373410)
2. [Sort Objects in Array by date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38168791/2373410)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorting date strings is ugly and cumbersome. Think object-oriented, instead of the tuple use a custom struct or class with a stored  `Date` (yes!)  property and a computed property for the string representation. It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @vadian I understand, but using the alternative `Date` does not work well with my current implementation...is there a better solution to sort the date `Strings` then just switching to `Date` objects?

Comment: Then consider to change your implementation. Don't fight the framework.

Comment: You could write your own custom sorting logic for your specific string representation of dates, but as @vadian already said before, changing your implementation to work with `Date` objects is the easier and better solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Foundation

var tupleArray = [("08/30/17", 9.0), ("08/30/16", 30.0), ("07/30/17", 5.0), ("05/30/17", 5.0), ("05/28/17", 6.0)]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"

tupleArray = tupleArray.sorted { 
    guard let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from:$0.0), let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from:$1.0) else { return false}
    return date1 > date2
}

print(tupleArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your creating an `Object` that would have your `String` and `Double` as properties. And you can make a Data as a computed property which will be computed on String value. And do sorting using the `Date` computed property.

I'm sure this will make your life much easier and re-rewriting your code from tuples to objects. Later on it will be really hard to find the bug while sorting Strings.. I'm sure that your first case when there were 3 tuples in an array was just a coincidence that it sorted it in a right way (this is a guess)..